# database error in sqlite using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am getting an error in sqlite db. The script works fine in windows but not in linux.

I am trying to get the table names from two databases(there will be only one table in each table) and make select queries on those tables.

Code -

```
db1 = r"C:\Users\X\Documents\sqlitedb\8007.db"
db2 = r"C:\Users\X\Documents\sqlitedb\8008.db"

conn = sqlite3.connect(db1)
conn2 = sqlite3.connect(db2)
conn.execute("ATTACH '{}' AS db2".format(db2))

res = conn.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
for name in res:
    tblname1 = name[0]
    #print(tblname1)

res2 = conn2.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
for name in res2:
    tblname2 = name[0]
    #print(tblname2)

res1 = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM main."""+tblname1+"""
                   WHERE IDKey NOT IN
                     (SELECT IDKey FROM db2."""+tblname2+""")
                """).fetchall()
res2 = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM db2."""+tblname2+"""
                   WHERE IDKey NOT IN
                     (SELECT IDKey FROM main."""+tblname1+""")
                """).fetchall()
```

The error is -

`select_mismatched_files
     """).fetchall()
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SELECT": syntax error`

The error is in this line --

```
res2 = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM db2."""+tblname2+"""
                   WHERE IDKey NOT IN
                     (SELECT IDKey FROM main."""+tblname1+""")
                """).fetchall()
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: i dont think the `"""` will work. Have you tried using `'`?

Comment: No. Let me try.

Comment: also.... those paths should not be valid in linux

Comment: The paths are changed in Linux.

Comment: @chade_ If I use single quote then I am getting a red mark. Probably the line is not correct -- `res2 = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM db2.'+tblname2+' WHERE IDKey NOT IN(SELECT IDKey FROM main.'+tblname1)).fetchall()`

Comment: I think it should be `... NOT IN(SELECT IDKey FROM main.'+tblname1+')').fetchall()`

Comment: How you quote your strings in *Python* has nothing to do with it. Please include a [mcve]. In other words: what do `tblname1` and `tblname2` contain?

Comment: @chade_ It worked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transcript from the comments (corrected):

chade_ (me):

> No. Let me try.

Prithviraj Mitra:

> If I use single quotes, I'm getting a red mark in my editor. Probably this line is not correct:

```
res2 = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM db2.'+tblname2+' WHERE IDKey NOT IN(SELECT IDKey FROM main.'+tblname1)).fetchall()
```

chade_:

> I think this line should be like this (closing `)` bracket wasn't enclosed in `'`):

```
res2 = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM db2.'+tblname2+' WHERE IDKey NOT IN(SELECT IDKey FROM main.'+tblname1+')').fetchall()
```

Prithviraj Mitra:

> It worked. Many thanks.

I'm answering this so other users with the same problem can easily determine the answer that was provided.